# How to modify data in a Text File in VB .NET

Tags: vb.net

i have text file more than 2000 row like these:
10
21
13
...
and i want to find the avarge of the 1440 row ,start from down to up and find the max,then find the avarge for each 30 row and put them besid the data and find the max of these avarge like this
max(od data)=----
max(averge)=-----

Comment: Please take more care when asking a question. If you aren't even willing to invest an extra minute of effort to write clearly, why should anyone invest any effort in trying to help you?

Comment: Dear if you can't understand my question just inform me otherwise i try hard to make it clear

Answer (score 2):

While the question shows a lack of effort, I'll still give some basic guidelines to help your search.

***Here are some things you are going to have to understand to tackle your problem:***

**1. How to handle text files in .NET**

You can easily process files using the System.IO.File class. This class has several static methods that are very useful. (Static methods allow you to call the method without explicitly creating an object

- [System.IO.File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) Reference on MSDN
- [System.IO.File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) This method lets you read each line into an array

  - ReadAllLines is most useful when the file is short enough to read all at once. At 2000 rows this should not be a problem. If you had millions of rows you would have to look at how to work with something called streams (deal with data in small chunks)

**2. How to convert a String to a number**

The strings you read in with ReadAllLines aren't very useful as strings. You need to convert them to numbers to do math with them. And of course there is a class for that...

- [System.Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) Converts a string to a number, throws an exception for bad formats
- [System.Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) Converts a string to a number, returns a default value on error

**3. How to do a for loop in VB.NET**

Any introductory tutorial should cover for loops, but here is one from MSDN

- [For Loops in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx)

**4. How to do something every nth time through a loop**

Use the modulus operator. This operator is like division, except that it returns the remainder. Every time the mod operation returns zero you have an exact multiple.

- [Example of using the Mod operator in VB.NET](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Language-Basics/ModOperator.htm)

**5. How to find the max in a list of numbers**

Have a variable to store the max value. Give it a value that is less than any value. Int32.MinValue is a safe value. Loop through every number. If it is larger than the max value, assign it to max value (it's the new max value). When you have processed every number max value contains the largest number you were able to find.

---

There are a few other details but if you can accomplish 1-5 you'll be able to ask a more specific question. This type of specific question will be better received by the stackoverflow community.

Happy coding.

Comment: Then please post the code you have so I can provide more specific advice.

Comment: Dear Many Thanx for your great help
can you please help me more in this issue

Comment: i have a text file with data like this
[12:02:05] 985 i need to seperate it into to array and find the max of the values and the time related to the max